# How to get a reference to recyclerveiw adapter Progress bar in post execute method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, adapter

Here is the scenario that I am trying to resolve. I have a Layout which contains some data to be submitted to a server, this `Activity` layout needs to upload multiple files (Attachments) which are listed using `RecyclerView.Adapter`. In each attachment that is listed in bottom part of my layout is a progress bar that shows status or the percentage of the file that has been uploaded to the sever. On the click of the submit button, it calls an `AsyncTask` and in the `onPostExecute` method of this `Activity` layout I want to upload my attachments.

What is the best way to overcome this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your async task is an inner class of an activity or fragment, you can simply call a method that lives in the activity or fragment from within onPostExecute

```
class MyActivity extends Activity
{

    public void showOrHideProgress(Result result)
    { 
        // your code here
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask
    { 
        private final WeakReference><View> progressBarReference;

        public MyAsyncTask(@NonNull View progress)
        {
            this.progressBarReference = new WeakReference<>(progress); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Result result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            showOrHideProgress(result); // or do something with progressBarReference
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much, Now How Can I get a reference to progress bar of each recycler view Adapter?

Comment: You could maybe pass a reference to the adapter or the progress View itself, into the AsyncTask but beware of memory leaks.  https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html

Comment: How to do that? , that's the real question.

Comment: Create an AsyncTask constructor and pass the desired objects as params.

Comment: Is this just only for one progressbar or multiple progressbar of recyclerview items?

Comment: if you want access to all of your progressBars, you can pass in a list or the adapter.